# MySQL 5.6 almost all login fail after upgrade

Tags: mysql

I have upgraded my openSUSE to the latest 13.1. During the upgrade, mysql was upgraded from 5.5 to 5.6.
I managed to upgrade the server (mysql_upgrade), after deleting the /etc/my.cnf

After the upgrade, my PHP based web apps are not connected to the server, with the following error:
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The relevant entry in my PHP file (which is the same for the last 2 years!) is:

```
(mysqli_real_connect($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "localhost",  "<USERNAME>",  "<password>", NULL, 3306, NULL,  196608))) ? $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] : FALSE);
```

What I have found is:

- PHP/mysql connector login to the server
- PHP/mysqli connector fails to connect to the server
- mysql -u USERNAME -p connects to the server
- mysql -u USERNAME@localhost **FAILS** to connect to the server.
- mysql listens at the standard 3306 port.

The netstat confirms it:

```
netstat -anpt | grep -i mysql
tcp        0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      8549/mysqld
```

The privileges have not changed after the upgrade! 
The relevant entries in the `user` table of `mysql` DB are:

```
SELECT `Host` , `User` , `max_user_connections` , `password_expired`
-> FROM `user`
-> WHERE `User`='<username>'

+-----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Host      | User         | max_user_connections | password_expired |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
| localhost | <username>   |                    0 | N                |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

Obviously, the @localhost is the problem, but why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use username as username@localhost. This looks to be incorrect by default mysql client will try to connect to localhost unless specified with -h.

So it should be -u USER and not -u USER@LOCALHOST

Comment: Did you read all information? The problem is not what I use, but how the mysqli tries to connect to the mysql server.